# Why can't I declare private static array of strings in my class?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to return an Array of Strings in a function within my class

When I try to use a private static array it returns me the following error:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in /home/developer/projects/api/src/public/Sql.php on line 17

This is my Class

```
<?php

namespace App;

/**
* Class Sql
*
* @return (Array) (Strings)
*/

Class Sql {
  private static $columns = (implode(",", array('product_id','model','viewed','ups','downs','location','price','quantity')));

  public function getColumns() {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(self::$columns);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit();
  }
}
```

Is there a problem in syntax or am I doing something I should not do?

What would be the right thing to do?

Comment: Because your calls to implode is not static, and must be resolved at runtime. Constants must be truly defined as constants.

Comment: you can't use an expression for a static variable. That means you cant use implode in your assignment just call it in  your constructor or the method where you access the static variable.

Comment: @Matt Clark, thank you for your answer! Not a duplicate, who scored as a duplicate, did not understand what I actually asked

Comment: Your question is no different the the one marked as a dupe. You both try to dynamically assign a constant, which you can not do.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private static $columns = ['product_id','model','viewed','ups',
                           'downs','location','price','quantity'];
```

I don't see why you're using `implode` anyway, since that would only result in `$columns` being a string (it would 'glue' the items in a single string: `product_id,model,viewed,ups...`).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked. I asked if the problem occurred because of syntax error or if what I was doing was impossible. As responded by @Matt Cark

Comment: @MateusFelipe You *literally* asked: "What would be the right thing to do?". My answer is exactly that; the right thing to do.